# containerize simple GUI written in qt c++ executable

Tags: c++, docker, user-interface, dockerfile, qt-creator

I have a huge executable ( qtcreator 5.12  GUI project written in c++) that runs when put in the same directory with some dlls. I use windows 10.0.18363 V 1909 and docker desktop.

Now I want to give that executable to a customer(he also uses windows10) . In order to do that I need to containerize my executable.

I am very new to docker, I have some basic knowledge about how to build&run containers. But I can`t succed to containerize my executable. I started to make a very simple c++ project (helloworldfromcpp) with qt-Creator like that

[image]

then I took the helloworldfromcpp.exe along with sone dlls into a directory and created a dockerfile in it:

[image].

When I doubleclick on the executable it runs OK. Can anybody help me what to put into my dockerfile in order to containerize it
? I tried that but it won`t work.

[image]

**- Do I need to use ubuntu or windows and which should I pull from dockerHub ?**

**- Do I need to put my executable into a conatiner or my whole qt project** (Executable only would be easier for me)?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Who said you needed to containerize a GUI application? Just ship the exe and its dependent DLLs, like all other Windows applications do.

Comment: Why would you even expect a Ubuntu container to work for a Win32 application?
Try following https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/virtualization/windowscontainers/quick-start/building-sample-app or even better, drop the idea of baking a container and go for a classic installer instead.

Comment: actually we have several customers who face lots of changes in their systems, computers etc. So we are forced to distribute patches etc to them.

Comment: @user3443063 With Docker you cannot run a windows application in linux

Comment: can I run it with docker desktop?